How can I equate two different ways to write $\Delta G$ if they aren't even the same units?
So $\Delta G$ can be written as $-RT\ln(K)$ and another way is $-nFE$. What I don't understand though is how they can be equated to each other when $-RT\ln(K)$ yields J/mol and $-nFE$ yields J.
How can they be equal when they don't quite describe the same thing? I'm really sorry for the basic question but this has been hurting my head for a while now. It doesn't help that equating these two leads to a lot of formulas that we frequently used in electrochemistry. So I sort of feel like I need to understand this to dig deeper.

The Gibbs free energy is an energy potential. It, and its changes, have units of joules. But sometimes it’s convenient to work in terms of the molar quantity (or the specific quantity, J/kg). If you see those units instead, the number of moles $n$ (or the mass $m$) has already been implicitly divided from the term. Good for you for checking the units—that’s essential to avoid errors by mixing up the absolute and molar (or specific) quantities.

Thank you so much for answering @Chemomechanics, I think I sort of get it. I still don't fully understand it but at least it's not as confusing as before.
